# Windows 10 won't show up after installing Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I've been trying to fix this issue for the past few hours now. I had kubuntu 17.10 installed before updating to 18.04, and before that ubuntu 16.04, and both recognized windows 10 in the grub menu, but after installing Kubuntu 18.04, at first the grub menu didn't appear at all, but then I did something in a file that made it appear, however windows 10 did not appear as an option in the grub menu.

I tried running sudo os-prober but nothing appears in the terminal, then I ran sudo update-grub and it only shows

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

It may have something to do with when I installed Kubuntu 18.04, as I made an EFI partition alongside /swap and the root partition, something I've never done before when I installed previous Linux distros.

I also tried adding a menuentry in the 40_custom file for windows 10, but that didn't work.

I also ran boot-repair, and this is the result:

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again. Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.
```

I'm thinking of installing Kubuntu again in the hopes of it working again, should I do that?

Edit2: I just reinstalled Kubuntu 17.10 over 18.04, typed

```
sudo update-grub
```

And everything is working again, windows 10 is an option in the grub menu. Thank you @kishea and @oldfred for trying to help me out. I'll wait for a few months until 18.04 stabilizes or something and download it then.

Comment: @karel  I'll go and try whats said in that link, hopefully it'll work.

Comment: It might work, but after reading your last edit I no longer think that it's a duplicate of that link because Boot-Repair has given you a different lead to follow.

Comment: If you have Windows and gpt partitioning, you must have an UEFI install. But if Boot-Repair or installer is asking for a bios_grub partition that is a BIOS install. Better to reboot and use UEFI, so you get an UEFI install. Best to have both systems UEFI or both BIOS and since Windows is UEFI, you will want Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: @oldfred I honestly do not know where I screwed up, I've been installing linux distros since I've bought this pc and they all worked with zero problems, I honestly don't know if I screwed up some settings when I made the usb bootable using rufus when I was on windows. So what do you think I should do? Should I make a bootable ubuntu usb drive and reinstall everything again? how do I make sure its in uefi mode?

Comment: You have to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode. And that can be settings in UEFI. And Windows may change some of those settings with updates. Make sure Secure Boot is off, most systems need legacy/BIOS/CSM mode off to boot in UEFI mode. A few still want legacy on, but you still select UEFI boot. You may also have to allow USB boot or full USB access settings in UEFI. UEFI installer should boot in either UEFI or BIOS boot mode from UEFI menu. What brand/model system? Many need UEFI updates also.

Answer (score 0):

Am Sure You Need to boot into windows. 
But to restore the boot menu, try boot-repair utility

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot repair && boot-repair
```

After running the utilty. view the log file to confirm the windows installation exists.

if all is fine you must have all your operating systems in the grub menu

if this does not work,

1. press `'c'` on the grub prompt
2. type `ls` command to view the partitions
3. type `insmod ntfs`
4. mark the listed partitions `(hd0,msdos1) or (hd0,msdos2) ... or (hd1,gpt1)`

   set root=(hdX,msdosX)
   chainloader +1
   boot

if it fails reboot and repeat the process steps above changing the **(hdX,msdosX)** to each of values you get in `ls` command.

Comment: I already tried to use boot-repair, and it gave me what is shown in the OP.

Comment: does manual boot from grub prompt work? am sure this must do. unless you deleted the windows partition

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by "manual boot from grub prompt", but the windows partition is there and not deleted, I can access all the files in the windows' partition from kubuntu's file manager, however the grub menu doesn't show windows as an option.

Comment: to manually boot from grub press 'c` at the prompt to get the grub console. type ls at this console to display all disk partitions

Comment: Read this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/833006/how-can-i-manually-boot-windows-from-the-grub2-terminal  to Boot From Grub 2

Comment: ok so I'm in the grub prompt, how do I know the numbers I have to plug in hdX and gptX?

Comment: use ls command to list all partitions first. it will give you the values.

Comment: I tried to plug in all the values from hd0, msdos1 all the way to hd1,gpt5. Some gave me that the file was not found (the bootmfgw.efi file), others gave me "unknown filesystem".

Comment: remember from your question it looks that you have GPT on the disk. so do not accept hd0,msdos1 or hd0,msdos2, etc. you must use hd0,gpt1 or hd0,gpt2.. the gptX is the partition number for your windows partition

Comment: showing the output of the ls command would help me find a solution for you

Comment: here's what shows up when I type ls: (hd0) (hd0, msdos3) (hd0, msdos2) (hd0, msdos1) (hd1) (hd1, gpt5) (hd1, gpt4) (hd1, gpt3) (hd1, gpt2) (hd1, gpt1)

Comment: from that, you have 2 harddisks or a CD and flash plugged in. please unplug any external bootable medium like flash or CD then run ls again

Comment: I do have 2 harddisks, an SSD with windows 10 installed on it, and an hdd with 300 gigs of it for linux. There are no flash drives or usbs connected to my pc.

Comment: is the SSD gpt partitioned?

Comment: sorry for being a noob, but how do I know that? I have gparted installed and when I view the device info, for the ssd it says: Partition table: msdos. while for the hdd, partition table: gpt. Is that what you meant?

Comment: now you will have to try for each partition you see in ls command. but for your case only try for set root=(hd0,msdos1) then proceed. still following the booting instructions in the link