# Can't boot into Windows 10 anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I currently dual booting between Ubuntu and Windows 10. However, whenever I try to boot from Windows 10 in grub it simply restarts and brings me right back to grub again.

I used boot-repair to create a pastebin:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pzJqP55FVV/

It's too long to paste it here.

But I have no idea what anything in the pastebin really means or how to fix grub. I have tried updating grub but the same problem occurs.

I ran sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1
 and got

```
Mounting volume... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x32cfb, last_vcn - 1 = 0x4027f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x32cfb, last_vcn - 1 = 0x4027f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x32cfb, last_vcn - 1 = 0x4027f
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Comment: I think that your windows has not fully shut down. Either you have fast boot option enabled in windows or something else happened. However, try to boot into windows from grub command line (check here https://askubuntu.com/questions/833006).

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu and run- `sudo update-grub` First see if it works..

Comment: I've already tried updating grub

Comment: Looking at your `boot-repair` log you definitely have a problem with Windows. Unfortunately though it's a **Windows** problem and off-topic in **Ask Ubuntu**. I suggest you post the problem in **Super User**.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix CV retracted.

Comment: I ended up just reformatting from scratch. Luckily I didn't really have anything important on this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to repair the NTFS drive from linux. Per [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows), do the following:

> Install ntfs-3g with sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g . Then run the
>   ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition

```
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdaX
```

if ntfsfix won't or can't fix your drive, you will have to run chkdsk from windows. You can boot from [Hiren's miniXP boot disk](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and use the command line there to run chkdsk.

Comment: I edited the OP with what I got after trying that command