# Unable to access BIOS from Sony Vaio SVE series laptop

Tags: grub2, bios, grubrescue, vaio, sony

I had Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot in my `Sony Vaio SVE15115ENW`. I thought of factory resetting my laptop and started the VAIO recovery system. During the resetting process, it did format the disk and some other copying of files and the system had to reboot for completing the recovery.
 
During the reboot, it got stuck in grub rescue mode as boot loader has not changed. Also, I can't choose any Linux partition as all the disk were formatted. To add salt to the wound, I am not able to enter the BIOS as well. This model has ASSIST button and whenever I try to turn on the laptop using ASSIST button instead of the power button, it gets stuck in a black screen instead of the Vaio Care Rescue Mode.
 
 
I guess as the recovery was not completed properly, the Vaio Care Rescue Mode is not available. And because of that, I am unable to enter the BIOS to change the boot device.
 
 
1. Is there any way to continue my recovery bypassing grub rescue? 
 
2. How can I access my BIOS now?

Comment: "I am not able to enter the BIOS as well" Then you are pressing the wrong key or are pressing too late. BIOS access is done prior to anything grub related. On a vaio the key to press can be a different one across models but should be printed on the screen when the logo shows. F2 or F3.

Comment: "Is there any way to continue my recovery bypassing grub rescue? " Linux. Insert the live session and boot from that. It might require BIOS access though to make it the option to boot. Windows not our cup of tea on AskUbuntu. The recovery though should also skip grub. That one is also executed prior to touching anything operating system related.

Comment: I agree with Rinzwind; your question is off-topic because you're asking about your hardware (not Ubuntu) and about Windows (not Ubuntu).  Yes from GNU grub you can boot a non-Ubuntu system, but you'll have to look at how your system has restored itself & do what is required for that.  This maybe helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/833006/how-can-i-manually-boot-windows-from-the-grub2-terminal  (note: *as stated you'll have to adjust for whatever you have including matching your bios config*)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I couldn't load the Vaio Care Rescue Mode using the ASSIST button, with the help of F2 button, I was able to enter BIOS(but they don't show that on startup). Created a bootable ubuntu USB and installing it now. Hopefully, the new installation will fix the grub issue as well. Thanks for spending time on my question.
Edit: The fresh installation of Ubuntu fixed the grub issue. On top of that, I was able to complete the recovery of my Windows as well(as I didn't run into grub rescue issue).